# django channels redis multiple consumers receive message a different times ensured?

Tags: django, websocket, redis, django-channels

Does this need to be implemented or is it in Channels already?

If I have a channel group with multiple consumers subscribed to it and one consumer is sent the message is the message lost to the rest of the consumers or does the message persist until all consumers see the message?

Or does the message persist for time until time is expired regardless of consumers seeing it or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Group` objects manages delivery to all consumers (where possible) and message expiry. But note that delivery is not ensured.

From the [documentation](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts.html#groups):

> Channels implements this abstraction as a core concept called Groups ...
>
> [Groups] also automatically manage expiry of the group members - when the channel starts having messages expire on it due to non-consumption, we go in and remove it from all the groups it’s in as well ...
>
> One thing channels do not do, however, is guarantee delivery. If you need certainty that tasks will complete, use a system designed for this with retries and persistence (e.g. Celery)